# add comma separated variables in to file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file into which I want to insert the string below:

```
export TRUSTED_PROXIES='"172.16.0.0/12, 172.17.0.0/12"'

[root@sasasas]# echo $TRUSTED_PROXIES
"172.16.0.0/12, 172.17.0.0/12"
```

But I am getting this error:

```
[root@sasasas]# sed -i  '2i trusted_proxies ='$TRUSTED_PROXIES''  log.conf
sed: can't read 172.17.0.0/12": No such file or directory
```

However, if I run the command below with the actual value it works:

```
sed -i  '2 i trusted_proxies =172.16.0.0/12, 172.17.0.0/12'  log.conf
```

How can I escape the comma separated env variable values and insert into a file? I am using Linux.

Command I tried are as follow

```
sed -i  '2i trusted_proxies ='$TRUSTED_PROXIES''  log.conf
sed -i  '2i trusted_proxies ="$TRUSTED_PROXIES"'  log.conf
sed -i  "2i trusted_proxies ='$TRUSTED_PROXIES'"  log.conf
sed -i  "2i trusted_proxies ="$TRUSTED_PROXIES""  log.conf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your variable contains spaces, and you are passing it unquoted, the shell tries to expand it and what `sed` actually sees is the second value as a file. This is probably easier to understand if you run `set -x` so you can see the expanded command executed by the shell:

```
$ set -x
$ sed -i  '2i trusted_proxies ='$TRUSTED_PROXIES''  file
+ sed -i '2i trusted_proxies ="172.16.0.0/12,' '172.17.0.0/12"' file
sed: can't read 172.17.0.0/12": No such file or directory
```

As you can see above, the actual command being run is:

```
sed -i '2i trusted_proxies ="172.16.0.0/12,' '172.17.0.0/12"'
```

So `sed` is looking for a file named `'172.17.0.0/12"'`. The fix is to double quote the variable:

```
sed -i  '2i trusted_proxies ='"$TRUSTED_PROXIES"''  file
```

Or, more simply, double quote the whole `sed` command and use single quotes around the printed value:

```
sed -i  "2i trusted_proxies ='$TRUSTED_PROXIES'"  file
```

Comment: Hello Terdon

I tried all the option you shared before posting this , command executed without error but doesnt insert values to file 

not sure what's the issues and some times it inserts as $TRUSTED_PROXIES not as actual value.

regards,
SAM

Comment: @Samurai If you tried these, then please [edit] your question and include the exact command and what they did. I have tested both of the solutions I give and both work fine so I suspect you did something slightly different.

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning this, but below command worked for me
sed  -i "2i trusted_proxies =$TRUSTED_PROXIES" log2conf

also I tried with below AWK it also helped me.
awk 'NR==2{print "'"trusted_proxies =$TRUSTED_PROXIES"'"}1' log2.conf

Answer (score 1):

```
Inputfile

praveen@praveen:~$  cat k3
10
20


TRUSTED_PROXIES='"172.16.0.0/12, 172.17.0.0/12"'

awk -v TRUSTED_PROXIES="$TRUSTED_PROXIES" 'NR==2{$0="trusted_proxies="TRUSTED_PROXIES"\n"$0}1' k3 >k3_temp && mv k3_temp k3


output

10
trusted_proxies="172.16.0.0/12, 172.17.0.0/12"
20
```

Comment: Thank you Praveen for you help, your solution is also working :)

Comment: Please vote for my answer

Comment: It's more complicated and less efficient to manipulate `$0` with `NR==2{$0="trusted_proxies="TRUSTED_PROXIES"\n"$0}1` than simply printing the text you want before it `NR==2{print "trusted_proxies="TRUSTED_PROXIES}1`